# Unity3D how to make 3D object respond to OnMouseDown()?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, click

[Scene and Inspector](https://i.gyazo.com/676eaf59557ec9aadbdc0ce7c6fae520.png)

[Script](https://i.gyazo.com/c0433885a7c9fb62ca6f7cb5e9bf2e42.png)

Hello all,

This is my first time posting here, but I've got a (possibly really stupid) problem. Im looking to make a simple 3d viewer to use in a web page and I want to do this throught Unity (WebGL). This 3D interactive viewer needs to respond to clicks and pass a message to another part of the website.

the things that are going to be clicked are coming from Cinema4D.

my problem shown in the pictures is I want these boxes to be clickable (they will work as filters for another part of the site). But I have not yet found a way to easily do this (I've seen Ray casts passing but I think that that is not needed for something as basic as this).

I am a rookie but willing to learn, if anybody can educate me what im doing wrong that would be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your Scene View your script is called `Container_On Click` but your code shows that the class is named `JustAFunction`. Please make sure both names are identical.

Comment: Do not use `OnMouseDown`. Use the `EventSystem`. See #6 from the answer in the duplicate.

Comment: but when I do that I get the following error (thats why I changed the name):
Assets/Scripts/Container_OnClick.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The namespace `global::' already contains a definition for `Container_OnClick'